# does the IE supports a click event in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this code `$('.cke_button__source').click();` but when im running it in IE its not clicking. any sort of code that trigger that even in all browsers? im currently using the latest IE as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes should work in IE. If you are trying to locate an id you should be using '#' not '.'. It doesn't look like you have any event handler assigned to the click. What are you expecting to happen when you call click? Try something like this:

```
$('.cke_button__source').click(function() {
  alert("it worked!");
});
```

If you are trying to literally fire the click event of the button you might try this:

```
$('.cke_button__source').click(function() {
  $('.cke_button__source').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: im trying to locate a class.. does it need to be an ID?